# Java project(Web Application)

Tags: java, jsp

I wanted to start the new java project(an Web Application). Since I'm just the beginner, I wanted to know what all I required to start the project. Can I start with the basic knowledge I have or I need anything more. As far as I know To build web Application I guess I need JSP. I don't want to use HTML, How do I start? Please help me.

Best learning links on JSP would be helpful.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/

Comment: This is it??? with the help of this can I build basic web application?

Comment: First of all you must learn how to ask.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you want to make a web application without html? you may use frameworks, but you will end up using html eventually. In an MVC (Model View Controller) the html (plus css and javascript) would be your View. I have a tip for you: Groovy, Grails and for the IDE: IntellijIdea. With these 3 tools and the twitter bootstrap css framework, you can reach great results within little time and groovy is a programming language that you will simply going to love. It is built up onto java and is way easier than java, and you can even write java code in a groovy class, it will magically works. You can mix java and groovy in a groovy class it will compile and work perfectly. Grails is a web MVC framework to use with groovy and it will simplify your life. It uses a .gsp instead of .jsp (jsp stands for java and gsp for groovy server page). By the way, when you meet IntellijIdea (full version) you will never want to see eclipse, or netbeans again (my opinion), because it is simply perfect

I'm sorry, I didn't understand if you really enjoyed the explanation I gave you or if you were being ironic, but I'll add a piece of information that might change your mind (if you were ironic) check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8d1hp8n1stA they are teaching how to build up a twitter (almost clone) with groovy and grails easily in 90 minutes. For begginners in java, and web programming it might seem a little hard to follow because they skip many low level steps, but you will get the hang of it easily watching that video and trying some beginners grails guides out there

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information, sure I'll try Groovy and java.